# How to fix GpuArrayException: ('Missing Blas library', 5) for theano (in python 2)?

Tags: python, gpu, theano, blas

I am running a code that uses Theano to model deep learning algorithms. I am attempting to use GPU for that (NVIDIA Quadro P1000). I have already tested it with the Theano code for testing GPU, and it shows that the GPU is being used. I am using Python 2.7 on Windows.

When I try to run my code, I get the following error:

> GpuArrayException: ('Missing Blas library', 5) Apply node that caused
>   the error: GpuGemm{inplace=True}(GpuFromHost.0,
>   TensorConstant{1.0}, GpuFromHost.0, GpuFromHost.0,
>   TensorConstant{1.0}) Toposort index: 6 Inputs types:
>   [GpuArrayType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, scalar),
>   GpuArrayType(float32, matrix), GpuArrayType(float32,
>   matrix), TensorType(float32, scalar)] Inputs shapes: [(2, 2400), (),
>   (2, 600), (600, 2400), ()] Inputs strides: [(9600, 4), (), (2400, 4),
>   (9600, 4), ()] Inputs values: ['not shown', array(1., dtype=float32),
>   'not shown', 'not shown', array(1., dtype=float32)] Outputs clients:
>   [[GpuSubtensor{::, int64:int64:}(GpuGemm{inplace=True}.0,
>   Constant{1800}, Constant{2400}), GpuSubtensor{::,
>   int64:int64:}(GpuGemm{inplace=True}.0, Constant{0}, Constant{600}),
>   GpuSubtensor{::, int64:int64:}(GpuGemm{inplace=True}.0, Constant{600},
>   Constant{1200}), GpuSubtensor{::,
>   int64:int64:}(GpuGemm{inplace=True}.0, Constant{1200},
>   Constant{1800})]]

**HINT**: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.

**HINT**: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.

Has anyone faced this error before?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [blas](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) or [lpack](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/) installed on your machine. I would also go through the rest of the [requirements for Theano](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/requirements.html) one by one and make sure that you have them installed. Specifically you might want to check **NVIDIA CUDA drivers and SDK** because you are running on an NVIDIA card.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have installed openBLAS and cuBLAS, but the error is still the same. I have installed NVIDIA cuda toolkit as well, but I will go back and check everything.